# can not read information from config file

Tags: java, netbeans-7, java-7, configuration-files

I wrote a java program and I use a config file that read all static information from it.
I used config files many times but this time, the program can't read information from it.

here's my `Config` class:

```
public class Config {
    private static final PropertiesReader PROPS_READER = new PropertiesReader("/config.properties");
    public static final int HOUR = PROPS_READER.getInt("hour");
    public static final int MINUTE = PROPS_READER.getInt("minute");
    public static final int SECOND = PROPS_READER.getInt("second");
    public static final Long DELAY = PROPS_READER.getLong("delay");}
```

here's my `PropertiesReader` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesReader {
    private final Properties PROPS = new Properties();
    public PropertiesReader(String path){
        try {
            PROPS.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
    public String getString(String key) {
        return PROPS.getProperty(key);
    }
    public int getInt(String key) {
        return Integer.valueOf(getString(key));
    }
    public long getLong(String key) {
        return Long.valueOf(getString(key)) ;
    }
}
```

Here's the place where I call the `Config`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Config.HOUR);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Config.MINUTE);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Config.SECOND);
```

and it's the error I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HOUR
```

Confige file:

```
# To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.

hour=11
minute=3
second=0
delay=1200
```

I'm using `Netbeans 7.3` as my IDE and `jdk1.7`.
I should mention that whenever I don't use the config file, my program works fine.
It's the first time I got this problem and I can't fix it any way. I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please share the config file

Comment: Clean the project and recompile it. A runtime `NoSuchFieldError` is smelly

Comment: Set the MINUTE value first to see what happens.

Comment: it makes no difference.now it gives an error about minute field

Comment: I have cleaned and built it many times but it doesn't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey your code not even compile... Where is defined getString() in PropertiesReader class?

I've simplified a bit but this should work (place your property file in the root of your project):

```
package my.stuff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;

public class TestClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Config.HOUR);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Config.MINUTE);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Config.SECOND);

        System.out.println(cal.toString());

    }
}

class PropertiesReader {
    private final Properties PROPS = new Properties();
    public PropertiesReader(String path){
        try {
            PROPS.load(PropertiesReader.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
    public int getInt(String key) {
        return Integer.valueOf((String)PROPS.get(key));
    }

}


class Config {
    private static final PropertiesReader PROPS_READER = new PropertiesReader("/config.properties");
    public static final int HOUR = PROPS_READER.getInt("hours");
    public static final int MINUTE = PROPS_READER.getInt("minutes");
    public static final int SECOND = PROPS_READER.getInt("seconds");
}
```

And here config.properties content:

```
hours=10
minutes=22
seconds=30
delay=10
```

Comment: hi.actually the method getString exists in my code and I forget to add it here

Answer (score 0):

the problem caused by a mistake caused by myself. In the program I called another program which it also has config files so whenever I run the program, it read from a wrong config file.

So I changed the config files names and addresses and the problem solved! I don't know It was my problem or netbeans bug!!!